# Dependenc Injection inside external Jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I have a problem with Dependency Injection inside an external Jar. The result always is null. I am using spring framework and java8.

My main has the following code:

```
package com.a.1

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.b.2"})
@Configuration
public class Main{  ... }
```

I have a test that call to the library

```
package com.a.1.test

public class test {

RequestMethod requestMethod = new RequestMethod();
requestMethod.method();
```

This RequestMethod is in a library (other Jar):

```
package com.b.2

public class RequestMethod {

@Autowired
private Headers header;

    public String method(){
    ...
    }  
}
```

The class Headers has the annotation @Service. An always the result is null.

```
package com.b.2

@Service
public class Headers{
...
}
```

The problem is that Headers is not being injected in RequestMethod. Could someone explain me how I have to prepare the Spring project to inject this dependecy?

Thank you very much in advanced

Comment: Doing `RequestMethod requestMethod = new RequestMethod();` bypasses Spring. Regardless of the amount of annotations you put on it.

Comment: Yes, That was the reason, now I have to refactor this RequestMethod. Thank you other time.

Answer (score 1):

1. `RequestMethod` sould have a `@Service`-Annotation.

   ```
    package com.b.2

    @Service
    public class RequestMethod {

    @Autowired
    private Headers header;

      public String method(){
       ...
      }  
    }
   ```
2. In the Test-Class `RequestMethod` sould be `Autowired`.

   ```
   package com.a.1.test

   public class test {

   @Autowired
   RequestMethod requestMethod;
   ```
3. Your Test should be a Spring-Test

   ```
   package com.a.1.test

   @SpringBootTest
   public class test {

   @Autowired
   RequestMethod requestMethod;

      @Test
       public void test(){
        requestMethod.method();
      }

   }
   ```